# Retrieving values from different tables via inner join

Tags: php, inner-join

I am unable to retrieve values from different tables using inner join, The output always doesn't retrieve anything.. Also, there is no error message and I'm unable to determine what went wrong in my code.. Can someone please help? I would appreciate it very much. Here is a part of my code..

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("student_records",$con);
    if(isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    {
        if($_COOKIE['username']!='admin')
        {
            $tbl6=mysql_query("SELECT A.LName, A.FName, A.MName, B.YearLevel
            FROM student as A INNER JOIN stud_course as B ON A.StudNo=B.StudNo INNER JOIN course as C ON B.CourseCode=C.CourseCode INNER JOIN religion as D ON A.ReligionID=D.ReligionID
            WHERE A.StudNo = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username'])."' ");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl6))
            {
                echo "<td>".$row['LName']."</td><td>".$row['FName']."</td><td>".$row['MName']."</td><td>".$row['Course']."</td><td>".$row['YearLevel']."</td><td>".$row['EAdd']."</td><td>".$row['ReligionName']."</td></tr>";

            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ALSO, DON'T TYPE IN CAPS. IT'S THE ONLINE VERSION OF SHOUTING.

Comment: @JohnConde - Do you have that comment saved somewhere, cut and paste?

Comment: @jared Farrish. Yes. There's a link to the Github Gist floating around here somewhere.

Comment: try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @John Conde Thank you for the suggestion. :) Can I also know if there is something wrong on how I executed the query?

Comment: @John Conde is wright
use MySQL Improved Extension
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner Joins require that data exist in both the tables included in the join.  In your case, you have four tables, and any one of those tables could be missing relevant data:

```
SELECT A.LName, A.FName, A.MName, B.YearLevel, C.Course
FROM student as A 
INNER JOIN stud_course as B ON 
    A.StudNo=B.StudNo 
INNER JOIN course as C ON 
    B.CourseCode=C.CourseCode 
INNER JOIN religion as D ON A.ReligionID=D.ReligionID
WHERE A.StudNo = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username'])."' "
```

- If there is no record in the `student` table with a `StudNo` equal to the username cookie, you will get no data.
- If the student does not have any records in the `stud_course` table, you will get no data.
- If the `CourseCode` in `stud_course` does not exist in the `course` table, you will get no data.
- If the student's `ReligionID` is null or has a religion that is not in the `religion` table, you will get no data.

I would suggest breaking the SQL into smaller pieces (or possibly switching each `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) to debug and discover where the problem is.

Note, you have to make sure to add the `Course` and `Eadd` (not sure what table that's from) fields to your select list if you are going to try to use it.

Comment: I should also note that personally I don't like aliasing tables.  I feel it's more clear if I use the table name throughout the SQL.  But that's just me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try what you have suggested. :)

Comment: there's an error message which tells that the index is undefined and it points to this line.. echo "<td>".$row['LName']."</td><td>".$row['FName']."</td><td>".$row['MName']."</td><td>".$row['Course']."</td><td>".$row['YearLevel']."</td><td>".$row['EAdd']."</td><td>".$row['ReligionName']."</td></tr>";

Comment: @scott.korin - a +1 for the solution, and I wish I could give you another +1 for the remark about aliasing. It's not just you! Aliases are so important for many operations (for example self-joins, tables that are the target of multiple joins), but at least 90% of queries I see use them needlessly.

Comment: @kdot, you don't have Course & EAdd in your SELECT list.

Comment: @kdot - your query requests fields `LName`, `FName`, `MName` and `YearLevel`. Your `echo` is trying to output the values of `Course`, `YearLevel` and `EAdd`, which weren't requested. Those are the indexes not found. Add the fields to the SELECT list.

Comment: i'm sorry I didn't eloborate my problem there.. this is the query I used pertaining to the error .. "SELECT A.LName, A.FName, A.MName, B.YearLevel
    FROM student as A LEFT JOIN stud_course as B ON A.StudNo=B.StudNo LEFT JOIN course as C ON B.CourseCode=C.CourseCode LEFT JOIN religion as D ON A.ReligionID=D.ReligionID
    WHERE A.StudNo = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username'])."' "

Comment: I already solve my mistake there, I didn't include it on the column that i want to retrieve in the query.. Btw, the suggestion of scott.korin works. thank you very much for you're help. I will also take your advice about aliases. Thanks again! God bless! :)